# JavaScript Node.js Promise <pending> in .map

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an api that takes in a userId, finds the Item associated with that, then I need to find all Accounts associated with the itemId.

I keep getting `[Promise <Pending>]` when I `console.log`
Any clue how to resolve this?

```
router.get('/:userId', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { userId } = req.params

    const items = await Item.find({
      userId: userId
    });

    const accounts = items.map(
      async item => {
        await Account.find({
          itemId: item.itemId
        })
    })

    console.log(items)
    console.log(accounts)
    res.json(accounts);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});
```

Comment: async functions return a promise.  accounts is an array of promises.  you need to use Promise.all

Comment: yes, an async function always returns a promise ...and in your case, the promise will resolve to undefined since your map callback doesn't return anything

Comment: you may as well just do `const accounts = items.map(item => Account.find(itemId: item.itemId))` - no need for async/await, and you'll also end up with a Promise that resolves to what you intended

Comment: @JaromandaX I tried your solution and got 
`Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'NativeTopology'
    |     property 's' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'sessionPool' -> object with constructor 'ServerSessionPool'
    --- property 'topology' closes the circle
`

Comment: that's nothing to do with "my way" - that's a problem with the data not being able to be converted to JSON - as I have no idea what `Account.find` returns, you'll need to manipulate the returned data to get what you NEED from the object that is returned by that call

Comment: something like `const accounts = items.map(item => Account.find(itemId: item.itemId).then(result => return the part of the result you need))`

Comment: ahh gotcha. thank you for your time , I'll keep poking around but at least you helped get me closer to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

async functions return Promise.  accounts is an array of Promises.  You need to use Promise.all.  Also your map function isn't returning anything.

```
  router.get('/:userId', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { userId } = req.params

    const items = await Item.find({
      userId: userId
    });

    const accounts = await Promise.all(items.map(
        item => Account.find({
          itemId: item.itemId
        })
    ))

    console.log(items)
    console.log(accounts)
    res.json(accounts);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});
```

Comment: `async x => { return await y(x);}` ... is better written `x => y(x)` - with the same results :p edit: which you've just done now ... lol

Comment: ya, caught that later.  the code actually had some syntax errors in it.

Comment: I tried your answer and got `Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'NativeTopology'
    |     property 's' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'sessionPool' -> object with constructor 'ServerSessionPool'
    --- property 'topology' closes the circle

`

Comment: also tried     `const accounts = items.map(
      (item) => {
        return PlaidAccount.find({
          itemId: item.itemId
        })
      }
    )`

Comment: `res.json(await Promise.all(accounts));`?